# Call own function with a completion handler

Tags: swift, recursion

I have a method to create an account:

```swift
func createAccount (completion: @escaping (_ succes: Bool, _ message : String)->()) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: createMail(), password: createPassword()) { (result, error) in
        if let _eror = error {
            //something bad happning
            print(_eror.localizedDescription )

            if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: _eror._code) {
                if(errorCode.rawValue == 17007) {
                    print("acount exist")
                    createAccount(completion: (Bool, String) -> ()
                } else {
                    //call itself and try it again
                }
            }
        } else {
            //user registered successfully
            print("user registered")
            return completion(true, "");
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error when the software creates an account with an email that already exists, which is good (see the `else` statement - `//call itself and try it again`).

What needs to happen is that the function needs to call itself again to try it with a different email.

I tried to put `createAccount(completion: (Bool, String) -> ()` in the `else` case, but that didn't work.

How can I call the `createAccount()` function again in the else case?

Comment: The `createAccount` call inside `if(errorCode.rawValue == 17007)` seems to be missing a closing bracket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the same paramter again

```
createAccount(completion:completion)
```